# I want to use GeoComply frameworks in Xamarin iOS. How can I use this, any leads?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, static-libraries, beacon

I downloaded GeoComply-(With PinPoint) sdk and it is having 3 framework which needs to be embed in project. My problem is am working on Xamarin Forms and want to create a static library which contains all 3 frameworks and use it in my xamarin projects.

I am unable to find any articles or document on the same. Please suggest.
Any lead would be highly appreciated.